# Redirect to different pages after Login with Spring Security

Tags: spring, hibernate, struts2, spring-security

How can I redirect different types of users to different pages after login.
for exemple, redirecting standard users to a /homepage.html page and admin users to a /admin.html page.
Note that I am using struts2, spring, hibernate, and spring security.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [redirect to a special space following the role of user spring security](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23812214/redirect-to-a-special-space-following-the-role-of-user-spring-security)

Comment: Create custom authentication success handler.

Comment: I am trying to do this, but it does not work for me 
I will add the code in a answer

Comment: If it doesn't work add it to your question. And don't ask same question multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like a custom `loginInterceptor` that checks for a valid login then returns different `Action.SUCCESS_ADMIN` which would redirect you to your intended page

```
<action name="login" class="login">
        <result name="success">home.jsp</result>
        <result name="sucess_admin> admin.html>
        <interceptor-ref name="loginInterceptor"></interceptor-ref>
    </action>
```

Your action would obviously be defined somewhat differently then mine that's just one I grabbed from my project to further explain my suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

MyAction.class

```
public String execute() throws Exception {
    if(user=="home_user"){
      return "home";
   }else if(user=="admin_user"){
     return "admin";
   }else{
      return "guest";
   }
}
```

Your struts.xml

```
<action name="login" class="controller.MyAction">
    <result name="home">home.jsp</result>
    <result name="admin">admin.jsp</result>
    <result name="guest">guest.jsp</result>
</action>
```

try it..